# ssh.exec_command("shutdown -h 17:00 &")

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I have a Python Paramiko script that sends commands to remote hosts on out intranet. There are times when I would like to send the shutdown command to several hosts at once. The issue is that the shutdown command simply sits and waits unless you background it. I have tried using the ampersand (bare as above, or escaped: \&). Here is a small test program. My os is RHEL Linux 5.9 (Python 2.4.3). Note that the sudoers disables requiretty for some users.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("<hostname>",username="<my username>", password="<mypassword>")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo /sbin/shutdown -h 17:00 \&")
stdin.write('\n')stdin.flush()
data = stdout.read().splitlines()
for line in data:
    print line
```

Comment: `&` only makes sense when run from (certain) shells - it's treated specially. So if exec_command bypasses the shell then it will be entirely useless.

Comment: If it is indeed the case that exec_command bypasses the shell, consider 1) spawning a shell (as the command) and using `nohup/&` from within that context, 2) using `at` 3) using `screen`. Also, see `nohup` in general.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue using the shutdown command as it is intended. First do not escape the ampersand (\&). Since the shutdown command does not return anything to stdout, I just eliminate those lines dealing with the output. The reason for wanting to use shutdown with a time is for user notification.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("<hostname>",username="<my username>", password="<mypassword>")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo /sbin/shutdown -h 17:00 &")]
ssh.close()
```